# How to forward domain name to blank page?

Tags: dns-hosting, domain-name, domain-parking

The domain host automatically sets the DNS nameservers to a parked domain. How can the settings be changed so that entering the URL instead gives a null (404) result or blank page?

Comment: Change the DNS entries to point to a web server which returns the page/status code that you want.

Comment: what web server results in the 404 page

Comment: You will need to set one up.

Comment: not sure how to do that

Comment: if dont know what you doing then serverfault.com is the wrong page please move on to superuser.com as this is for private and not business related question

Comment: maybe just change settings to a non-existent DNS

Answer (score 2):

**You cannot do this with "DNS" alone**, you will require DNS hosting along with website hosting.

Once you have both DNS, and WEBSITE hosting (the former often provided free of charge by 'most' domain providers); you'll need to do the following:

1. Update nameservers (if not done already)
2. Update/Create DNS record for your primary zone(domain) with an A record pointing to your hosting provider.
3. Depending on your hosting provider, you may simply be able to delete your `index.html` (or equivalent) and that'll result in a 404 being shown.

Ultimately most 'consumer'-grade hosting providers will be able to offer you support to do what I have described, with instructions suited to their exact platform.